# Rails Server needs restart every time I make javascript changes inside assets pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am not sure how this is not working, I have one js file inside app/assets/javascripts/xxxx.js, whenever I am doing anything, it requires to restart the rails server each time to reflect.

I am running the application in development mode and my config/environments/development.rb looks correct.

Here how it looks,

```
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true  

  # By default, don't send emails in dev mode
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

 # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.enabled = true     


    config.dev_tweaks.autoload_rules do
      keep :all

      skip '/favicon.ico'
      skip :assets
      keep :forced
    end  

end
```

Can someone help?

Comment: try do not digest, `config.assets.digest = false`

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines:

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.debug = false
```

If this doesn't work,  maybe you got some remnants of old compiled assets. Try with a little `rake assets:clobber` to remove all previous compiled CSS versions, this should load your new CSS everytime you restart.

Comment: Thanks for comment. FYI....I do not want to precompile..m working in dev environment...its something weird :(